# Calling programmatically Catalog product save does not call observer in Magento?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento-1.7

I have created the observer to insert product attributes in table when product save

```
<adminhtml>
         <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <Test_price_save_product_data>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Magetest_test_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>saveProductAttr</method>
                    </Test_price_save_product_data>
                </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
  </adminhtml>
```

saveProductAttr() this insert product attributes in seperate table when product save in admin end.

Now i have separate script to save more than 7000 products as like below

```
    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(1);
    require_once 'app/Mage.php';

    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('admin');
    Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("type_id",Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);

foreach($products->getData() as $val){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$val['sku']);
    if ($product) 
        {   
            $product->setData('status',1);
            $product->save();
        }
}
```

When i ran the script, it save the product one by one but it does not trigger **'catalog_product_save_after'** observer.since i need to insert 7000 product attributes respectively in another table using this observer.

What i have done wrong on this ? Kindly advice.

Answer (score 0):

Observer isn't firing because Magento never loads the `<frontend />` area of the application. As for solutions, we could try moving your observer to the `<global />` area. only `<global />` events fire when you run a command line script.

```
<global>
         <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <Test_price_save_product_data>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Magetest_test_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>saveProductAttr</method>
                    </Test_price_save_product_data>
                </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
  </global>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because product was not modified. In Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php file function "save()" has the following code
    if (!$this->_hasModelChanged()) {
    return $this;
    }

If you edit any field of that product: `setData("name", "test");` it will work.

Comment: or even better $product->setData("_hasDataChanges", true);